# an array is given.it will return the unique numbers from given array

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

1.If  array  is null,  return null;
2.If array length is zero, return -1.
Here the return type should be string
I tried it but i don't know how to return null and -1; in this program.

```
public class Unique-Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {2,5,3,6,5,1};
        System.out.println(getUniqueNumbers(a));
    }
    public static String getUniqueNumbers(int a[])
    {
        String result="";
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
                if(a[i]==a[j])
                    count++;
            if(count==1)
                result += a[i]+ " ";
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: If you want to return null, try `return null;`.  If you want to return -1 but the result has to be a `String`, try `return "-1";`.  I'm not clear on what the issue is.

Comment: In getUniqueNumbers method put two if checks initially, if(a ==null) return null; if(a.length ==0) return "-1"; String result=""....  Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
public class Unique-Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {2,5,3,6,5,1};
        System.out.println(getUniqueNumbers(a));
    }
    public static String getUniqueNumbers(int a[])
    {
        String result="";
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
                if(a[i]==a[j])
                    count++;
            if(count==1)
                result += a[i]+ " ";
        }
if(result=="")        
return null;
if(a.Length==0)
return -1;
        return result;

    }

}
```

if you want to check for -1, just do a int parse.

Comment: Thanq soo much Suraj